# Good Articles/book on neural networks

Tags: complexity-theory, artificial-intelligence, neural-networks

I search good articles or books on neural network. unfortunately i don't a lot of time and only now i started to research this field. so i actually search a good source that will give the fundamental (basic theory and tools to understand complexed neuroal networks).
any suggestion?

Comment: I'm not an expert and I've read neither of these, but I heard that [Deep Learning Book](https://www.deeplearningbook.org/) and [Dive into Deep Learning](https://d2l.ai/) are pretty good.

Comment: Book recommendation questions typically don't work well here.  To make them work well, we ask that you (1) provide specific criteria/requirements ("good" is too vague), (2) show the research you've done (e.g., which books you've already considered and whether they meet your requirements or not).  Usually you can get a good list of candidates by looking at what different universities use in their classes, and checking book reviews (e.g., on Amazon).  We're not a site for book reviews or opinions.